# Passing parameters to a bat file and then passing them to a php script

Tags: php, cmd

I having trouble passing command line parameters, that were passed to a bat file, onto a php script

This is what I have:

```
@echo off
echo %1%
set foo=%1%
php %~dp0%myscript.php %1% %2% %3%
```

The first three lines work.  The 4th line works if it is just:

```
php %~dp0%myscript.php
```

also works if I hard code the parameters:

```
php %~dp0%myscript.php a b c
```

but if it is:

```
php %~dp0%myscript.php %1% %2% %3%
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not open input file: c:\dev\123
```

I have tried all of the following syntax for the parameters:

```
%1
%1%
"%1"
"%1%"
%*
%*%
"%*"
"%*%"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `php "%~dp0myscript.php" %1 %2 %3`. Note no trailing `%` in `%~dp0`, `%1` etc. Read also http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured it out:

```
set pth=%~dp0%myscript.php
php %pth% %1 %2 %3
```

seems I have to do it in two steps - looks as if too much concatenation is confusing it.

Comment: I don't have any official information about this behaviour but I found out by trial and error that the Windows command interpreter is able to do **only two** replacements of environment variables in a command line. This is probably its behaviour since the 80s and it's sad they didn't improve it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

There are evil superabundant `%` percent signs in your line:

```
php %~dp0%myscript.php %1% %2% %3%
         ^               ^   ^   ^
```

This line is then parsed as follows:

- `php` :taken literally;
- `%~dp0` :results to full path of your `bat` or `cmd` script;
- `%myscript.php %` : results to empty string;
- `1% %2% %3%` : results to `123` as every `% %` results to empty string and trailing `%` as well.

As per [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), use

```
php %~dp0myscript.php %1 %2 %3
```